# Ethereum contract "checksum" and contract simulating

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, function, simulation

I was looking at different contract simulators and I was wondering how are they made. I can see that they determine all of the functions that a given contract have, eg:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Currently there is no limitation on max wallet

--------------------------------------------------------
Buy Tax: 0.60%
Sell Tax: 0.00%
--------------------------------------------------------
⚠️Very Low buy & sell tax!⚠️

⚠️Be careful low tax buy tokens might change with additional transaction!⚠️
⚠️Be careful with the frontrunner bots!⚠️
--------------------------------------------------------

Checksum: 0x721ead2 - All: 849, Scams: 104, 12.25%
Functions:
0xdd62ed3e - allowance(address,address)
0x095ea7b3 - approve(address,uint256)
0x70a08231 - balanceOf(address)
0x313ce567 - decimals()
0xa457c2d7 - decreaseAllowance(address,uint256)
0x39509351 - increaseAllowance(address,uint256)
0x06fdde03 - name()
0x8da5cb5b - owner()
0x715018a6 - renounceOwnership()
0x95d89b41 - symbol()
0x18160ddd - totalSupply()
0xa9059cbb - transfer(address,uint256)
0x23b872dd - transferFrom(address,address,uint256)
0xf2fde38b - transferOwnership(address)
```

I was wondering - how is that possible? Are they really decompiling binary code and then deploy the contract, call all the functions, add liquidity and then try to buy it? And what is the **checksum** `0x721ead2`?